# How to read a pdf file saved in mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

I have successfully uploaded pdf files to the database but now when I am trying to read the files I'm getting issue "Failed to load PDF" when I click on the link. I have checked my browser plugins there is no issue with it.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
mysqli_select_db($con,"mahmood_faridi");

$query = "SELECT id, name FROM upload";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die('Error, query failed');

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==0){
    echo "Database is empty <br>";
}
else{
    while(list($id, $name) = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<a href=\"download.php?id=\$id\">$name</a><br>";
    }
}

if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id    = $_GET['id'];   
    $query = "SELECT  content FROM upload WHERE id = '$id'";       
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die('Error, query failed');
    $row =  mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    $content=$row['content'];   
    header('Content-type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $content . '"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
    ob_clean();
    ob_flush ();
    @readfile($content);
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

This is the “save file” code:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
if(isset($_POST['upload']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0)
{
    $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    $tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];

    $fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
    $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
    $content = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$content);
    fclose($fp);

    if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        $fileName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$fileName);
    }

    mysqli_select_db($con,"mahmood_faridi");
    $query = "INSERT INTO upload (name, size, type, content ) ".
    "VALUES ('$fileName', '$fileSize', '$fileType', '$content')";

    mysqli_query($con,$query) or die('Error, query failed'); 
    mysqli_close($con);
    echo "<br>File $fileName uploaded<br>";
} 
else
    echo "File not uploaded"
?>
```

Comment: Can you save the file you're getting sent? What is the file size? Are you certain that your SQL is working properly?

Comment: See about joins. You have more queries here than is necessary

Comment: SQL is working certainly. File size is 2.05MB and data type used is mediumBlob. No I cannot save the file too.

Comment: Tell me where to edit. @Strawberry

Comment: Sorry, re-reading, you do not need a join. But I cannot see that you need the first query either

Comment: I need first query to check whether the database has some pdf files or not. -Strawberry

Comment: How save you pdf to db? raw? have you tried with other filetypes?

Comment: No I have not. What sort of file types should I save? I want the user to download the file or to read it online.

Comment: @HK007 For testing. To check if your problem is generic or pdf-related. Also, can you show the code of mysql file storage?

Comment: @fusion3k I have edited the code. And the code belo contains the code of mysql-file storage.

Comment: Your code is very insecure and it would be very easy to download every single upload without knowing the id. Simply use an ID of `' or 1 = 1 LIMIT 0, 1 --`, `' or 1 = 1 LIMIT 1, 1 --` etc. like so: `file.php?id=' or 1 = 1 LIMIT 0, 1 --`. Use prepared statements and bind your variables to avoid this.

Comment: I will do that later but at the moment I want to know why my pdf files are getting corrupt when I save them in the database. @h2ooooooo

Comment: @HK007 Is your database connection UTF8? Is your database table UTF8? Is your PHP saved in UTF8? Does your HTML use UTF8? Do you send UTF8 headers in your code? Most likely you're using different encodings over different stuff hence corrupting it. Try to simply upload a file with the contents `foobar æøå` and see if it's the same content everywhere.

Comment: First of all, I would try with a simple text file to easy check if the files are identical, then with an image like jpeg. Also: 1) use prepared statement; 2) instead of storing file in raw format, try to pre-encode-it with base64 (it will be bigger).

Comment: I have replicated your code (w/out modification of encoding) and for me it works fine. Maybe there are a problem of encodings, pay attention at @h2ooooooo comment

Comment: I've checked everything else but I don't know how to send utf8 headers to my code. Kindly guide me about this as I'm new to php.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to post this as a comment, but it got a bit too long.

When saving the file to the database, try base64_encoding the content, and then base64_decoding it when reading it out.  PDFs look odd when viewed in text, and the collation of the database can affect the way it saves, or even what is saved.  If one single character changes, you'll have a corrupt PDF.

Also make sure that error reporting is turned off, and that you have no spaces being output alongside the PDF which will also show as the file being corrupt.

I'd also consider splitting the functionality you have out into different files.  It looks like everything is in one file there, which can lead to output happening when you don't fully expect it, again corrupting a download.

As an alternative, can you not save the PDF to disk and store the location in the database.  You can then read the file as needed and output it, and then there's no issue of the PDF content being corrupted within the database.  If you go down this route, make sure you give them unique names as two files could be uploaded with the same name and you might accidentally overwrite one.

Comment: I am new to php so I've searched for the syntax but I don't know where to use in my code. Please guide me about this.

Comment: I've tried using this too. I encoded the content to base64_encode during saving the file and decoded it as echo base64_decode($content); but still the error  persists :(

Comment: I've used your advice of uploading files to a destination folder. But I don't know how to give path. Guide me about this.

Comment: @HK007 when you do `move_uploaded_file()` you will provide a location to move the file to.  It's that location which you need to store in the database so you know where the file is located.

Comment: I've got you point and now when I upload a file its address is saved in the database and file is save in the destination folder. But Now I'm totally confused about how to download file from there using that path. suggest me a function to use.

Comment: you should be able to pass in the file location from the database to `readfile()` which takes the file name as a string as the first parameter (see @fusion3k s answer for an example)

Comment: Following his answer gives the same error :( Please guide me about this.

Comment: I have been stuck on it from the last two days :(

Comment: When uploading the file, check you are storing it correctly and it exists in the filesystem (with the size you would expect).  In `readfile()` make sure you pass the absolute path to the file.  Also make sure that the file has the correct permissions to be read by the webserver.  If these are all correct, try downloading the file via FTP or similar and opening it on your local machine; does that work?

Comment: The file is stored correctly I'have checked the presence in the destination folder and checked its size too. I was retrieving path from database but I was unable to check its value in storing variable so I gave direct path in readfile() the file was loaded but the there were stars and dots on the whole browser screen

Comment: Here is new code . 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35235044/download-a-pdf-file-using-path-saved-in-database-php

Answer (score 0):

Oooooops!

We all concentrated about encoding and database storing, but the problem is another!

When you output your PDF, you get the content from database, but you send this content to the user through:

```
@readfile($content);
```

`readfile($content)` outputs the contents of the file with filepath `$content`, but in `$content` there is not any filepath!

You simply change this line of code in

```
echo $content;
```

and your script will works.

(Read more about [`readfile`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php))

Comment: Thanks for the answer but brother its still not working.

Comment: You have a problem in your configuration, maybe with encoding. I have tested your code and on my server is ok for pdf. Try to encode in base64

Comment: @HK007 PS: Are you sure that the filesize of your file doesn't exceed the `mediumblog` max size? Also check if the filesize of retrieved content is the same of original file.

Comment: yes my filesize is 2.05 MB. I've checked the encoding and changed all to utf-8. database is utf8mb4. I don't know how to change encoding of table.

Comment: base64_encode and base64_decode are new for me I've checked for the syntax but I'm confused about where to use it.

Comment: The downloaded file has a size of zero bytes. And is not still loaded in the browser though I've changed the encoding to utf-8.

Comment: zero bytes=no file. are you sure that the files are properly loaded in the database? you have perform a check line-by-line, i suppose.

Comment: The files were uploaded correctly in the data base there was a problem while downloading. I checked the file in the database. Now I'm trying another way I just uploaded the files in a directory and now I'm trying to give path in the data base. Can you help me in this?