# Download a pdf file using path saved in database?

Tags: php, pdf

I want to download a PDF file from a folder but when I try to read the file it gives the error "failed to load PDF". When I try to download it, a corrupt file is downloaded.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
    if(!isset($con)){
        echo "Database not connected";
    }
    $db=mysqli_select_db($con,"mahmood_faridi");
    $query=("SELECT * FROM books");
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
    while(list($id,$file)=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<a href=\"download.php?id=\$id\">$file</a><br>";
    }

    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        $id    = $_GET['id'];   
        $query = "SELECT  link FROM books WHERE id = '$id' limit=1";
        $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
        $file=mysqli_fetch_object($result); 
        header('Content-type: application/pdf');
        header('Content-Disposition: inline');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

        @readfile($file);
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_object($result);` will certainly _not_ return a path to a file, but an object...

Comment: so what should I use iinstead?

Comment: Also take care: your code is vulnerable to sql injections. You want to fix that!

Comment: Ah yea, `$file = mysqli_fetch_object($results)['file_path_colum_name_here'];`

Comment: What do you mean by "what should I use iinstead"? Well dump the object, take a look and decide!

Comment: Brother I have checked for the headers, I have dumped the fetch object and I have used @Andrew Coder way too but nothing works :(

Comment: Remove the "@" from the readfile command and see if it pumps out an error.

Comment: @AndrewCoder it still does not work :(

Comment: It does not pumps an error but it does not works :(

Comment: Hi, @HK007 So, problems also w/ filepath? `LIMIT 1`, not `LIMIT=1` **Have you tested the query result?** **Have you tested the query result?** **Have you tested the query result?** **Have you tested the query result?** **Have you tested the query result?**

Comment: You claim you dumped that object. Great! So what does it contain? Please add that information to the question above by using the `edit` button right below the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script there are many errors.

When we write a php script, first of all, it's good practice activate error reporting; this is not a caprice: showing errors is our first allied in code debugging. To activate error reporting, put this two line at top of your script:

```
error_reporting( E_ALL );
ini_set( "display_errors", 1 );
```

This not resolve completely error reporting, because compile errors (like if you write `eco` instead of `echo`) are omitted, and you will see only a blank page. When this occur, to check where your code fails, you have to read the Apache logfile. You can find the location of Apache logfile googling “Your OS Apache error log default path”. So, if you use OS X, you can search "Mac Apache error log default path".

When you are sure that your code works fine, is preferable to remove (or comment) these line, for security and esthetic reasons.

Another important ally, especially for a newbie, is the PHP Official documentation; copy-and-paste can be good, but only if followed by a careful reading of the code: we need to understand every command! In your case, if you had read the chapter about [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php), you would understand that

> header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include, or require, functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called.

This is your first big error: you first display the list of available files, then call `header()` function, that fails. If you had activate error reporting, the mistake it would have been reported.

So, your code must continue in this way:

```
if( !isset($con) ) die( "Database not connected" );
$db = mysqli_select_db( $con, "mahmood_faridi" ) or die( "Unable to select Database" );

if( isset( $_GET['id'] ) )
{
    $id    = $_GET['id'];
    $query = "SELECT link FROM books WHERE id = '$id' LIMIT 1";
```

Then, check the result. In our original code, you write `WHERE id = '$id' limit=1`. If you had checked the result, you would have got this message:

> Query error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=1' at line 1

and you would have realized that something was wrong in the query.

```
    $result = mysqli_query( $con, $query ) or die( "Query error: " . mysqli_error( $con ) ); 
    if( !mysqli_num_rows( $result ) ) die( "ID $id Not Found" );

    $file   = mysqli_fetch_object( $result );
```

Then, check if the file exists. In your original code, you write `readfile( $file )`, but `$file` is an object (`$file = mysqli_fetch_object( $result )`), not a filepath. The filepath is actually `$file->link`.

If you had checked if the file exists and activated error reporting, you would have got these messages:

> Warning: file_exists() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, object given in /your/script/path.php on line XX
>   File Not Found

and you would have the kind of error and the line to check.

```
    if( ! file_exists( $file->link ) ) die( "File Not Found" );

    header( 'Content-type: application/pdf' );
    header( 'Content-Disposition: inline' );
    header( 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary' );
    header( 'Accept-Ranges: bytes' );

    @readfile( $file->link );
```

Also important, place a `die()` or `exit` after `readfile()`, otherwise your script will output also following html code, and your pdf file will result corrupt:

```
    die();
}
```

Now, you can place the code to display your files list (that will be executed only if pdf file is not sended); also in this case, it is good to check the result step-by-step:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM books";     // <-- brackets are superfluous, but are not error
if( ! $result = mysqli_query( $con, $query ) ) die( "Query error: " . mysqli_error( $con ) );

if( !mysqli_num_rows( $result ) ) die( "Database empty" );
```

In your original `while` loop, you write as url `"<a href=\"download.php?id=\$id\"`: the backslash (`\`) behind a double-quoted string is a character escape that means “not interpret-it, print-it”, so the dollar sign is printed as-it and the variable is not passsed. Your effective link is 'http://example.com/download.php?id=$id' instead of 'http://example.com/download.php?id=1'. Watch out for the little things.

```
while( list( $id, $file ) = mysqli_fetch_array( $result ) )
{
    echo "<a href=\"download.php?id=$id\">$file</a><br>";
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

... and your script is done.

Comment: Thank you brother for such explanation. I'm going to figure it out and I will report you soon. :) :)

Comment: Thank you very much for giving me your time and intellect . Thank you very very much :) :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeking to access a pdf file from a server using a url from the database you might want to look into the file_get_contents function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

You would need to pass the url of the pdf in as a parameter to the file_get_contents function.

```
file_get_contents($file);
```